# Automatically open a second tab onload in jsp using struts2 tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, struts2, dojo

I have two tabs with `id=created` and `id=awaiting`.

I want to open a second tab (with `id=awaiting`) on load

I am using tabpanel of struts2 tags

I have used:

```
<%@page import="com.itextpdf.text.log.SysoLogger"%>
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags"%>
```

Here is my code for tabs:

```
<sx:tabbedpanel id="HomeTabs">                                  
<sx:div id="created" label="Created By Me" href="" theme="ajax" ></sx:div>
<sx:div id="awaiting" label="Awaiting My Review" href="" theme="ajax"></sx:div>
```

On load first tab (Created By Me) is opening. 
Now I want send tab (Awaiting My Review) to open on load.

Please provide your valuable suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: dojo tags are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `selectedTab` attribute of `<sx:tabbedpanel>`. Pass an `id` of a tab you want be selected on page load.Check example given below

```
<sx:tabbedpanel id="HomeTabs" useSelectedTabCookie="true" selectedTab="awaiting">
    <sx:div id="created" label="Created By Me" href="" theme="ajax" ></sx:div>
    <sx:div id="awaiting" label="Awaiting My Review" href="" theme="ajax" ></sx:div>
</sx:tabbedpanel>
```

Hope this will help you.